# How to behave when there is a wild boar in your way

Tags: animal-behaviour, boars

I ask this question because I met them often in the forest. In the most cases they only run away but in one case the boar blocked our way through a valley. It only looked at us. It did not attack but we could not chase it away with yelling.

Perhaps yelling was the wrong idea? But how should you behave? And how can you prevent to be attacked?

Comment: Duplicate of http://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/9999/5565

Comment: @Escoce why is this animals behavior considered aggressive?

Comment: It isn't necessarily, but this question has been for the most part asked and the answer provides how to react and what to expect from all levels of aggression or non-aggression. I just linked to the question, but I do not have the power to close a question. You need to have moderator privileges to that, and those decisions are peer reviewed and usually discussed before anyone flips the switch. If we leave questions too similar laying around you run into fuzzy information. If you think you have a better answer or even think the question can be improved. Do that with the original question.