# Fending off a boar with an axe?

Tags: hunting, boars, hunting-gear

So, this is likely a very very dumb question but I came across [this question about wild boars](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/9999/how-to-react-to-an-aggressive-boar) while researching boar hunting and I was wondering if an axe would be at all useful against a boar if it was the only weapon/tool you had to use? I know that when hunting boar spears and bows have been used in the past but I can't find anything on how effective an axe might be. Because of the tough hide, I am assuming the axe wouldn't do much but, could it be used to at least distract the boar long enough to run for the nearest tree? I have no hunting experience at all, so like I said at the beginning this could be a very dumb question.

Comment: Do boars ever threaten people?  The two times I've seen a boar family they took no notice of me at all (although they so suddenly crossed that I nearly crashed into them on my bicycle, and mama may have had something to say if i had crashed into one of her little ones).

Comment: @gerrit Maybe you should google "killed by wild boar"... Only things meaner are cassowaries & hippos. (Okay, maybe a bit of an exaggeration.)

Comment: My Google Search results did not result in much evidence of their danger (for example, see http://www.britishwildboar.org.uk/index.htm?publicsafety.htm ).  Cows and dogs are more dangerous.

Comment: From @gerrit 's link "When not continually shot at or harassed, wild boar ... can become quite tame..." Sounds like OP is planning on shooting at them. Any animal can be aggressive when threatened or protecting young. Sure, there is hyperbole surrounding this question, just like when people ask questions about how big of a gun they need to defend themselves from black bears. Personally, wouldn't worry about it, & certainly wouldn't enter into hand to hand combat with a boar, even with an axe. But do boars EVER threaten people? Sure.

Comment: Are you planning on bringing the axe specifically for the boars, or will you have it for other reasons?

Comment: Well, like I said in my question I was doing research on boar hunting, and I was merely curious. The axe came about because I know hunters and campers, or at least the ones I know personally, will bring an axe or hatchet with them for firewood or for chopping meat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most useful thing you can do with an axe in case of a boar attack is *throwing it into the bushes and climbing the nearest tree*.

Trying to melee with a charging boar is a bad idea<sup>TM</sup>, regardless of what kind of weapon you are carrying. This mostly includes guns also, as a charge by a boar will not give you enough time to do much of any thing before contact...

I.e. if you want to be safe in the face of wild boars, think of ***prevention*** instead of *defence*.

For example as suggested by [this site](https://www.nparks.gov.sg/gardens-parks-and-nature/dos-and-donts/animal-advisories/wild-boars):

> - **Be calm and move slowly away from the animal.** Do not approach or attempt to feed the animal.
> - **Keep a safe distance and do not corner or provoke the animal** i.e. by using a flash while taking pictures of it.
> - **If you see adults with young piglets, leave them alone.** These are potentially more dangerous because they may attempt to defend their young.

Comment: That argument was not helpful - it wasn't appropriate in comments. Feel free to have it in chat if you must.

Answer (score 2):

RE: Fending off a Boar with an Axe. Sure, you *could* do that. BUT... chances are high that you will likely not incapacitate the Boar enough immediately since you may not penetrate deep enough with the blow to deliver an immediately incapacitating blow.

NOTE: An aggressive Boar will use their tusks and attempt to gore you in the area of your femoral artery (inner thigh). IF they successfully manage to target this area, you will likely bleed-out very rapidly and likely die from the blood loss.

IF you're going to have to go toe-to-toe with a pissed-off Boar, and all you had was a Hatchet... I'd probably try like hell to land strong blow to the base of his neck, hoping to damage the CNS (Central Nervous System) for a rapid incapacitation.  I'd have to imagine the head would move too much as he was approaching to be a target that you'd be able to effectively score a hit on it in the heat of the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Not going to distract with an axe and then climb a tree.  You got to the tree or not before the hog got to you.  Hogs are usually in brush without a lot of trees you can climb.

An axe is a formidable weapon.  You  would need to time the charge but you can break flesh.  If it does latch on to you then strike the hind quarters.

I would certainly want more than an axe but I would take that over nothing.

I certainly would not hunt boar with an axe. Most boar (and feral hog) hunting is with an assault rifle or small deer rifle. For defense my weapon of choice is a shot gun with light shot then stack a bigger shot behind the first two. The light shot will take out their eyes so they can't see you. If they keep coming keep shooting.

They do not attack often.  Piglets are what you need to stay away from as mama will defend her piglets.

I ran the numbers a boar can get up to 30 mph but that take 1000 meters to get up to speed and they are just not likely to attack from that distance. So more like 20 mph.  That is 30 ft / second.  Can get off 3 shots from an automatic rifle or pistol in 1 second and 2 from a manual shotgun.  A body shot from 30 feet is an automatic from good marksman and head shot from a top marksman.  I was going out for target practice at my friends 300 acres and it turns out some other people were hunting and scared one to me. I dropped to my butt clicked off 2 and dropped him.  Not a chance in hell I could have climbed a tree in that time even if there was tree.  I would take my chances with an ax over no ax.  Another time my buddy that is better marksman and hunter than me dropped a boar attacking my dog with a shotgun in two shots without even blinking.

Comment: I don't get the down votes.  A battle ax is used in battle as a weapon.  Even hatchets are used in battle and lethal.

Comment: I think it might have to do with the first couple of sentences. They are more of a dig at the other answer and can be left out. By the way, I did not downvote.

Comment: @Ricketyship Cool not arguing but "at least distract the boar" is from the question.  From an earlier comment the other question has no actual experience with boar.